# Migrating source code from PVCS to SVN

Tags: svn, github, migration, git-svn, pvcs

I am trying to migrate the source code from PVCS to Git.

While searching I found that PVCS can be first migrated to SVN and then to Gitwith the help of [this link](https://www.polarion.com/downloads/svn.php).

As, we are having many projects in PVCS. we wanted to take the dump of all the projects at a time rather than taking the single project dump.

Is there any other way to dump all the multiple projects in PVCS to (SVN or GIT repository) rather than repeating the same for each project?

Answer (score 0):

It seems better to repeat the process considering the best practice would be to have one Git repository per project.

So exporting one PVCS project to one new dedicated SVN repository would then facilitate the export of that one SVN repository to a new Git one.
And you can run that process in parallel.